# Custom Headers are lost in Camel while sending message to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have the following route. It is strange that the custom header value "myHeader" is lost at the consumer side of Kafka.

Can you please let me know what is the reason for this and how I can solve this issue.

```
from("file://inputFolder?delay=2s&noop=true")
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.setHeader("myHeader", constant("MY_HEADER_VALUE"))
.to("kafka:test-topic?brokers=localhost:9092");

from("kafka:test-topic?brokers=localhost:9092")
.log("${body}")
.log("***** myHeader: ${header.myHeader}")
```

The value of myHeader is an empty string though I set it as ""MY_HEADER_VALUE".

We use Apache Camel 2.20.2 and Spring Boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hi Claus,We use Camel version 2.20.2 and Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so this is not supported in this *older* Camel version you use. Its supported from Camel 2.22 onwards, see ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12503